# Place <a> elements inside two different divs

Tags: php, html

I have this structure on my page:

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;  
}

.div1{
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.div2{
  width: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 500px
}

.div3{
  width: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 500px;
}

.float_left{
  float: left;
}

.float_right{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2 float_left">
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="div3 float_right">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

And inside the two orange container's I want to put some smaller divs, but I read the data from a database. The first row should be in `div1`, the second in `div2`, the third in `div1` and so on.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM question ORDER BY question_id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
}
```

But how can I do something like that? Can I open a div container closed container to place a div container inside the container?

Comment: Do you have any knowledge in Javascript/jQuery? Yeah I know that suggesting these is way too mainstream but the solution using jQuery would be very simple...

Comment: Yeha i have some knowledge in jquery^^, but i need ajax then?

Comment: I guess it would be the cleanest option, but I was thinking about a 4th div, hidden, which would store all the values that came from PHP. Then, a simple jQuery would pull those values and append the odd indexed ones to div 1 and the even indexed ones to div 2. Sounds good?

Comment: So i dont need ajax. I write all data inside a hidden div and then? I can read them with a jquery function and move them into the other div's? via .append()?

Comment: Yep, that was my suggestion, but folks have already provided more clever answers below :)

Comment: folks? = dont use jquery and write the data into a php array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really read and try by yourself, this is pretty basic question.

There are many ways, here is one of them.

1. Declare 2 variables to store the results for `Div1` and `Div2`.
2. Declare a `count` variable and use the `odd` and `even` property to decide who turn is it to store the results.
3. Output the results.

**PHP:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM question ORDER BY question_id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

$resultsForDiv1 = "";
$resultsForDiv2 = "";

$count = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if ($count%2 == 0) {
        $resultsForDiv1 .= $row[0]; // You should change it to whatever data you need from $row.
    }
    else {
        $resultsForDiv2 .= $row[0]; // You should change it to whatever data you need from $row.
    }

    $count++;
}
```

**Html:**

```
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2 float_left">
    <?php echo $resultsForDiv1; ?>
  </div>

  <div class="div3 float_right">
       <?php echo $resultsForDiv2; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is that a good solution? Or is the way of @lucasnadalutti better with jquery?

Comment: @OrelErakis solution is the better. It is faster and more efficient than requiring the visitor to do unnecessary calculations. Also it does not require the visitor to have JavaScript enabled.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is store the data from the `$row` variable into new variables which you can then output in the two columns. Like this:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM question ORDER BY question_id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

// Use this to toggle column on the sql results
$left_right = true;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($left_right) {
        // Add to left column variable
        // [some code to add the data from $row to $left_column_content]
    } else {
        // Add to right column variable
        // [some code to add the data from $row to $right_column_content]
    }

    // Switch columns by inverting the boolean from true to false, false to true
    $left_right = !$left_right;
}

?>

<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2 float_left">
    <?php echo $left_column_content; ?>
  </div>

  <div class="div3 float_right">
    <?php echo right_column_content; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```